# Reducing Redundancy in sets of repetitive tasks in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm a beginner and I would like to know if there's any way to reduce redundancy in the following code:

```
if(checkBoxA.Checked == true) 
{  
   comboBoxA.Enabled = true; 
   textBoxA.Enabled = true; 
} 

string stringA = comboBoxA.Text; 
float floatA = float.parse(textBoxA.Text);

if(checkBoxB.Checked == true) 
{  
   comboBoxB.Enabled = true; 
   textBoxB.Enabled = true; 
} 

string stringB = comboBoxB.Text; 
float floatB = float.parse(textBoxB.Text);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can extract method with signature, for example
(string, float) GetInformation(CheckBox checkBox, ComboBox comboBox, TextBox textBox)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do this, wrap it in a function. Although, for setting the values you might want a container or a Tuple.

You can adjust the naming to a meaningful names.

Here's the container example:

```
public class Container
{
    public string StringValue {get;set;}
    public float FloatValue {get;set;}
}
```

```
private Container HandleState(CheckBox checkBox, ComboBox comboBox, TextBox textBox)
{
    if(checkBox.Checked == true) 
    {  
        comboBox.Enabled = true; 
        textBox.Enabled = true; 
    }

    return new Container()
    {
        StringValue = comboBox.Text;
        FloatValue = float.parse(textBox.Text);
    };
}
```

And call it like:

```
var resultA = HandleState(checkBoxA, comboBoxA, textBoxA);
var resultB = HandleState(checkBoxB, comboBoxB, textBoxB);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Winforms, you can group controls together and perform your operation on whole group. You can use 2 containers (Panels) and add comboBoxA and textBoxA to first one and comboBoxB and textBoxB to second. When check box is checked you can use below code to enable all elements within the appropriate container (I have used panel as container)

```
        foreach (var item in panel1.Controls)
        {
            (item as Control).Enabled = true;
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

All states are different and purposes are different so mostly you can not avoid.